# How to left join 2 tables with SUM() and MAX() grouped by date

Tags: php, mysql

i have table loadhistory (planning to "select only highest value per date" group by and order by date DESC)

```
| user_id | customer_id |     date    | bal |
    1           1         2015-02-27    500
    2           1         2015-02-27    650
    3           1         2015-02-28    450
    4           1         2015-02-28    620
```

and table transactionrecord (and planning to sum up values per date using SUM(bal) group by and order by date DESC)

```
| user_id | customer_id |     date     | bal |
    1           1         2015-02-27     50
    2           1         2015-02-27     20
    3           1         2015-02-28     10
```

But i want to join the 2 tables which would look like this:

```
|    date    |   balance    |   amount paid   |
  2015-02-28       620               10
  2015-02-27       650               70
```

im not good in joining tables. this is my code so far and not  working

```
$q = "SELECT a.customer_id, SUM(a.bal), a.date, MAX(b.bal) GROUP BY date 
FROM transactionrecord as a 
LEFT JOIN loadhistory as b ON b.customer_id = a.customer_id
WHERE customer_id = {$_COOKIE['id']} GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY date DESC";
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q );

echo '<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="45%">
<tr>
<td align="center"><b>Date</b></td>
<td align="center"><b>Balance</b></td>
<td align="center"><b>>Amount Paid></b></td>
</tr>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '
    <td align="center">' . $row['date'] . '</td>
    <td align="center">' . $row['MAX(b.bal)'] . '</td>
    <td align="center">' . $row['SUM(a.bal)'] . '</td>

';
```

what to change in my query to join the 2 tables with the SUM() and MAX() included? And is my using of $row['  '] in echo right?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL statement should look like this in order to achieve your desired result:

```
SELECT a.customer_id, a.date, MAX(COALESCE(b.bal, 0)) AS bal, a.paid
FROM (
  SELECT customer_id, date, SUM(bal) AS paid
  FROM transactionrecord
  GROUP BY customer_id, date
) AS a LEFT JOIN loadhistory AS b
  ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id AND a.date = b.date
WHERE a.customer_id = 1
GROUP BY a.customer_id, a.date, a.paid
ORDER BY a.date DESC
```

And in your php, you cannot refer to result columns using `MAX(b.bal)` or `SUM(a.bal)`; instead, you must alias the columns as I've done above. So you can refer to `MAX(b.bal)` as `bal` and you can refer to `SUM(a.bal)` as `paid`.

You mostly had the SQL right, I only

- removed a misplaced `GROUP BY` expression,
- added aliases for the aggregated (`SUM` and `MAX`) columns,
- put the transaction balance summing in a subquery to prevent multiplicative results for multiple rows in the `loadhistory` table
- qualified all mentions of `date` and `customer_id` columns, since those columns appear in both tables,
- added a `COALESCE` on `bal` in case the left join results in no matching `loadhistory` records,
- added a join criterion on `date` since records must have equivalent `customer_id` and `date` to match your requirements, and
- added `customer_id` to the `GROUP BY` clause because any non-aggregated fields in the `SELECT` clause should be in the `GROUP BY` clause for predictable results.

If you wanted to select the value with highest `user_id` per `date` in the table `loadhistory` instead of `MAX(bal)`, you would need to do something like this:

```
SELECT b.user_id, a.customer_id, a.date,
  COALESCE(b.bal, 0) AS bal, SUM(a.bal) AS paid
FROM transactionrecord AS a LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT h1.user_id, h1.customer_id, h1.date, h1.bal
  FROM loadhistory h1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(user_id) AS user_id, customer_id, date
    FROM loadhistory GROUP BY customer_id, date
  ) AS h2 ON h1.user_id = h2.user_id
         AND h1.customer_id = h2.customer_id
         AND h1.date = h2.date
) AS b ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id AND a.date = b.date
WHERE a.customer_id = 1
GROUP BY b.user_id, a.customer_id, a.date, b.bal
ORDER BY a.date DESC
```

Comment: thanks. hmm i'm getting an error in  
    
    <td align="center">' . $row['MAX(b.bal)'] . '</td>

what should i replace inside $row[' ']?

Comment: thanks a lot. hmm the bal returned correct results but paid does not.
'paid column' gave 20 and 140 instead of 10 and 70

Comment: i decided to SUM(a.bal/2) and it gave me the right values on amount paid column although the values are in 6 decimal places and i need only 2 decimal places. i'l just read other pages related on decimal places.
 thank you again, i learned a lot today.

Comment: Beware, the multiplicative results were due to the number of records in the `loadhistory` table. It's not good enough to divide by 2. See my updated answer for the reliable solution. And you can play with it here if you want: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ede08/9

Comment: yup, i notice the wrong results. thanks for your update. code works fine now. Thanks :-)

Comment: hi, its me again. what if i want to select the value with highest user_id per date in the table "loadhistory" instead of max(bal)? 
this is what i tried

        `SELECT a.customer_id, a.date, b.bal AS bal, a.paid
    FROM (
    SELECT customer_id, date, SUM(bal) AS paid
    FROM transactionrecord
    GROUP BY customer_id, date
    ) AS a LEFT JOIN loadhistory AS b
    ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id AND a.date = b.date
    WHERE a.customer_id = 1 AND user_id = MAX(user_id)
    GROUP BY a.customer_id, a.date, a.paid
    ORDER BY a.date DESC  `

i have updated my question, thanks. @gknicker

Comment: hi, its me again. what if i want to select the value with highest user_id per date in the table "loadhistory" instead of max(bal)? this is what i tried 
         `SELECT a.customer_id, a.date, b.bal AS bal, a.paid FROM ( SELECT customer_id, date, SUM(bal) AS paid FROM transactionrecord GROUP BY customer_id, date ) AS a LEFT JOIN loadhistory AS b ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id AND a.date = b.date WHERE a.customer_id = 1 AND user_id = MAX(user_id) GROUP BY a.customer_id, a.date, a.paid ORDER BY a.date DESC`  
i have updated my question, thanks.