# How to left join selecting value with the highest user_id

Tags: php, mysql, join

well this question is related to my previous question [How to left join 2 tables with SUM() and MAX() grouped by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790771/how-to-left-join-2-tables-with-sum-and-max-grouped-by-date)

what i changed is i added user_id column (auto incremented) and want to select value with highest user_id per date

i have table loadhistory ( wanted to "select only value with highest user_id per date" group by and order by date DESC.) 
so in this case, i want to select 150 for 2015-02-27 since it has the highest user_id in that date and 50 for 2015-02-28

```
| user_id | customer_id |     date    | bal |
    1           1         2015-02-27    100
    2           1         2015-02-27    150
    3           1         2015-02-28    150
    4           1         2015-02-28    50
```

and table transactionrecord (want to sum up values per date using SUM(bal) group by and order by date DESC)

```
 | user_id |customer_id |     date     | bal |
     1          1         2015-02-27     50
     2          1         2015-02-27     20
     3          1         2015-02-28     10
```

And i want to join the 2 tables which would look like this:

```
|    date    |   balance    |   amount paid   |
  2015-02-28       50               10
  2015-02-27       150              70
```

this is the code so far (i used the code i got from my previous question and edited it here in my new question hoping to arrive desired result but did not)

```
SELECT a.customer_id, a.date, (b.bal AS bal WHERE b.user_id = MAX(b.user_id) , a.paid
FROM (
SELECT customer_id, date, SUM(bal) AS paid
FROM transactionrecord
GROUP BY customer_id, date
) AS a LEFT JOIN loadhistory AS b
ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id AND a.date = b.date
WHERE a.customer_id = 1
GROUP BY a.customer_id, a.date, a.paid
ORDER BY a.date DESC
```

help please. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL use the first row by **group by**, so you must order it before you can use group by like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `loadhistory` ORDER BY user_id DESC) history GROUP BY date
```

So you can use the following query as solution:

```
SELECT h.date,h.bal as balance, t.amount as 'amount paid' FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `loadhistory` ORDER BY user_id DESC) history GROUP BY date) as h
JOIN
  (SELECT SUM(bal) as amount, customer_id, date FROM `transactionrecord` GROUP BY date) as t
ON h.date = t.date AND h.customer_id = t.customer_id
ORDER BY date DESC
```